# Mocking DirectoryStream<Path> without mocking iterator possible?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, powermock

I've the following piece of code:

```
        Map<String, String> fileContentsByName = new HashMap<String, String>();

        try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(directory))
        {
            for (Path path : directoryStream)
            {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(path))
                {
                    fileContentsByName.put(path.getFileName().toString(), new String(Files.readAllBytes(path)));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
```

I am attempting to test this method. I'm using `Powermock` to get the mocked `DirectoryStream<Path>`. However, when the test encounters for-each in the code, it blows up with a NPE. How can I specify the Paths in the DirectoryStream?

I've thought about changing the source code to use iterator and mocking the DirectoryStream's iterator to provide the desired paths but I am wondering if there a better alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the code snippet you provided above is defined in a class like so:

```
public class DirectoryStreamReader {

    public Map<String, String> read(Path directory) {

        Map<String, String> fileContentsByName = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(directory)) {
            for (Path path : directoryStream) {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(path)) {
                    fileContentsByName.put(path.getFileName().toString(), new String(Files.readAllBytes(path)));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return fileContentsByName;
    }
}
```

Then the following test will pass:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DirectoryStreamReader.class})
public class DirectoryStreamTest {

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void canReadFilesUsingDirectoryStream() throws IOException {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);

        Path directory = Mockito.mock(Path.class);
        DirectoryStream<Path> expected = Mockito.mock(DirectoryStream.class);
        Mockito.when(Files.newDirectoryStream(Mockito.any(Path.class))).thenReturn(expected);

        File fileOne = folder.newFile();
        File fileTwo = folder.newFile();
        Iterator<Path> directoryIterator = Lists.newArrayList(Paths.get(fileOne.toURI()),
                Paths.get(fileTwo.toURI())).iterator();

        Mockito.when(expected.iterator()).thenReturn(directoryIterator);

        Mockito.when(Files.isRegularFile(Mockito.any(Path.class))).thenReturn(true);
        Mockito.when(Files.readAllBytes(Mockito.any(Path.class))).thenReturn("fileOneContents".getBytes()).thenReturn("fileTwoContents".getBytes());

        Map<String, String> fileContentsByName = new DirectoryStreamReader().read(directory);

        Assert.assertEquals(2, fileContentsByName.size());
        Assert.assertTrue(fileContentsByName.containsKey(fileOne.getName()));
        Assert.assertEquals("fileOneContents", fileContentsByName.get(fileOne.getName()));
        Assert.assertTrue(fileContentsByName.containsKey(fileTwo.getName()));
        Assert.assertEquals("fileTwoContents", fileContentsByName.get(fileTwo.getName()));
    }
}
```

The key points here are:

- Uses JUnit's `TemporaryFolder` rule to create and discard some files for use by the test
- Uses PowerMockito to mock all interactions with `java.nio.file.Files`, this is a final class and the methods being mocked are static hence the need for PowerMockito
- Follows the PowerMockito advice when [mocking a system class](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System), specifically:

  - Use `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` annotation at the class-level of the test case.
  - Use the `@PrepareForTest({ClassThatCallsTheSystemClass.class})` annotation at the class-level of the test case.
  - Use `mockStatic(SystemClass.class)` to mock the system class
- This test is verified with Junit 4.12, Mockito 2.7.19 and PowerMock 1.7.0

Comment: Dumb question - Is using for-each on the `DirectoryStream<Path>` the same as invoking `iterator` on `DirectoryStream<Path>`?

Comment: Yes, the for loop construct is syntactic sugar over an iterator.

Comment: Good job in showing a working test! It would read a lot better with the use of static imports, though. But more importantly, I would suggest that a test that actually read a test directory with a couple of small files would be much better, with less code, no coupling to SUT internals, and no need for a mocking library (or two, in this case).

Comment: The question was all about **how** to mock the `DirectoryStream` returned by `Files` so I mocked those pieces but the interaction with `File` instances uses actual files created by the `TemporaryFolder` rule. Re the static imports; since the test is presented without import statements I think being explicit about the static imports might help avoid confusion. If I was writing this code+test for myself I suspect I would simply work with actual files which met the required conditions and I'd use static imports too :)

Comment: @glytching could you please answer this task, it similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444434/how-to-write-junit-test-for-directorystream