# How to write junit test for DirectoryStream

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit4, junit-jupiter

I have this function in a class called Test.java and it incudes;

```
public List<Path> getAllFoldersInTmp(String directory) throws IOException {
    final List<Path> files = new ArrayList<>();
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Path.of(directory))) {
        for (Path entry : stream) {
            if (Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
                files.add(entry);
            }
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

so basically it returns all folders as a list in the "../../tmp" path. I want to write a test for it, and this is how i done but it does not work:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class Testing{
    
    @Autowired
    Test test;
    @TempDir
    Path directory;
    
    @Test
    public void givenDir_whenUsingDirectoryStream_thenListAllFiles() throws IOException {
    
        File fileOne = directory.resolve("file1").toFile();
        File fileTwo = directory.resolve("file2").toFile();
    
        System.out.println(test.getAllFoldersInTmp("../../Temp")); //since the fileone and fileTwo are stored in `Temp/someRandomNumber` directory
    
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error;

```
 ..\..\Temp
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ..\..\Temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `@TempDir` you are free to not use some specific hard-coded paths (e.g. `"../../Temp"` in the snippent).

Basically, the temporary directory will be created for you automatically by `junit`. Then in the tests, you can manipulate it in the way you want, e.g. create files and directories.

If you need to get value of temporary directory path, you can simply invoke `toString()` on the field annotated with `@TempDir`.

For example, for your specific case following test can be written:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDir;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class FoldersResolverTest {

    @TempDir
    Path directory;

    // assume FoldersResolver wrapps getAllFoldersInTmp 
    FoldersResolver foldersResolver = new FoldersResolver();

    @Test
    void directoriesAreFoundAndFilesAreSkipped() throws IOException {

        Path fileOne = directory.resolve("file1");
        Path fileTwo = directory.resolve("file2");
        Path directoryOne = directory.resolve("directory1");
        Path directoryTwo = directory.resolve("directory2");

        Files.createFile(fileOne);
        Files.createFile(fileTwo);
        Files.createDirectory(directoryOne);
        Files.createDirectory(directoryTwo);

        // note directory.toString() returns path to the temporary folder created by junit
        List<Path> actual = foldersResolver.getAllFoldersInTmp(directory.toString());

        List<Path> expected = List.of(directoryOne.getFileName(), directoryTwo.getFileName());
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

**Note:** In general, `@TempDir` makes use of **the default system temporary file director**y. This depends on operating system, and normally can be found via environment variable. For example, `TMPDIR` on my system points to `/tmp` directory.

Comment: i have question about @TmpDir
how can i put the fileOne inot FileInputStream? The following paths could not be deleted

Comment: could cou help me here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712198/how-to-load-a-mock-file-from-mock-path

Comment: Hi @Catalina! I've noted the comments only recently. Added the answer in the question you posted.