# How to load a mock file from mock path

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to write unit test for a function which trys to get a file from disk and streaming it:

```
public InputStream downloadFile(String folderName, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File name = Paths.get("/tmp/portal", folderName, fileName).toFile();

    return new FileInputStream(name);
  }
```

my try code

```
 @InjectMock MyService myService;
   
    @TempDir
        Path mockDirectory;
     @Test
        void downloadFile() throws IOException {
     Path mockFile = mockDirectory.resolve("testFile");
            Files.createFile(mockFile);
     String folderName= mockFile.subpath(5, 6).toString();
     String filename= mockFile.getFileName().toString();
        InputStream inputStreamResult = myService.downloadFile(folderName, filename);
    }
```

the error is

> File: testFile dont exsits

Answer (score 1):

You receive an error `testFile dont exsits`, because there is a hard-coded path `"/tmp/portal"` in `downloadFile` method.

Below is an example of unit-testing that file is downloaded:

```
interface Service {
    Cipher getDecryptCipher();
}

class FileDownloader {

    private final Service service;

    public FileDownloader(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public InputStream downloadFile(String folderName, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = Paths.get(folderName, fileName).toFile();
        return new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), service.getDecryptCipher());
    }
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class FileDownloaderTest {

    @TempDir
    Path directory;
    @Mock
    Service service;
    @Mock
    Cipher cipher;
    @InjectMocks
    FileDownloader fileDownloader;

    @Test
    void fileContentIsDownloaded() throws IOException {

        String testFileName = "testFile";
        String testFileContent = "test text";

        Path testFile = directory.resolve(testFileName);
        Files.createFile(testFile);
        Files.write(testFile, testFileContent.getBytes());
        when(service.getDecryptCipher()).thenReturn(cipher);

        InputStream actualInputStream = fileDownloader.downloadFile(directory.toString(), testFileName);

        CipherInputStream expectedInputStream = new CipherInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(testFileContent.getBytes()), cipher);
        assertThat(actualInputStream).hasSameContentAs(expectedInputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i actually fogoten to write that the return value is something like this, new `CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), service.getDecryptCipher());` with your impementation i am getting error that the file could not be deleted, how to mock cipher? could you change the code accordinaly? i will then accept the answer :)

Comment: @Catalina I've updated the answer with mocked cipher.

Comment: i am getting this error : `WARNING: Error occurred while closing java.io.BufferedReader@706507f8
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized`

Comment: Also with this error :

`ed: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\catalina\AppData\Local\Temp\junit10056578990060702957\testFile: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: please help me :(

Comment: If you just copy-paste the code in the answer - does the test passes ?

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you. It passes without any issues on my system.

Comment: may i dicuss with you please on the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224254/discussion-between-catalina-and-oleksii-zghurskyi).